# How do I access my guest Linux VM server behind Mullvad VPN running on the guest?

Tags: linux, vpn, vmware, remote, local

I have a guest Linux server vm running on a Windows 10 host. My Linux VM is running Mullvad VPN while Windows is not behind any VPN. I can access the Linux server when I’m on my local network.

Outside of my local network, I have a VPN setup on my router which I can connect to remotely and access the host Windows 10 PC but I cannot access the Linux VM. The VPN is on its own subnet (`172.168.2.1/24`) while the Windows PC and Linux server VM is on the default subnet (`192.168.1.0/24`).

Locally I’m able to access both Windows PC and Linux server while connected remotely through VPN can access my Windows PC but not my Linux server.

How do I configure my network/Linux server VM to be accessible through the VM remotely?

Comment: If you are running a VPN on the Linux VM then you cannot connect to the Linux server directly unless you are attempting to connect via the VPN address. If you can connect via the LAN to that Linux VM it is because the VPN would not be enabled for LAN traffic. Thus when you connect on the local LAN there is effectively no VPN connection.

Comment: Most likely what you want/need is policy routing with the help of fwmark, so that replies for traffics that came from the Internet through the physical interface will not be routed into the VPN tunnel.